# Putting Text on a textPath using Svg in Krita

Tags: text, svg, krita

In Krita 4.2 ,the text tool doesn't provide the feature to put text on a path,but it does give the ability to curve  text using Svg scripting.

On using a Svg script to create  curved text (below) by using the  [textPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath) element ,the text simply vanishes.The curve below is constrained to an area between (0,0)(100,100)

What should be the syntax to create curved text with Svg in Krita?

```
<text <textPath d="M10,90 Q90,90 90,45 Q90,10 50,10 Q10,10 10,40 Q10,70 45,70 Q70,70 75,50">style="fill:#ffff00; letter-spacing:0; word-spacing:0; kerning:0; font-family:Segoe Script; font-size:18pt; font-size-adjust:0.16; font-weight:400; font-style:normal; font-stretch:0">This text is on a Curved Path</textPath></text>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, no.
But work is going on to support SVG2 text, lets see how far I can get, :D

Comment: Is there any update ?